# How to count occurrences of single digits followed by a particular character in R

Tags: r, regex, string, split, count

In R, for a given character string--for eg.:

```
this_str <- "1. blah blah. 2. blah blah, 50 blah. 3. Blah; blah blah June 21, 2016."
```

I need to count the number of times a single digit appears followed by a period. I can almost accomplish this using

```
> library(stringr)
> str_count(this_str, "[0-9]\\.")
[1] 4
```

However, this code is also counting the year `2016.` at the end of the last sentence. How could I modify `str_count(this_str, "[0-9]\\.")` so as to exclude such cases.

In my particular problem, I know the digits I want to count will be 1-9. So, one way might be to modify so as to exclude numbers containing more than one digit. But not sure how to code that up. It would also be nice to have a more general solution (where numbers to be counted can have more than one digit) if anyone can think of one.

Comment: I think `str_count(this_str, "(?<!\\d)\\d\\.")` is more appropriate for the current task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify a word boundary (`\\b`) so it would match a single digit followed by a `.` from the word boundary.  For 2016, there are 4 digits and it is not the case

```
library(stringr)
str_count(this_str, "\\b[0-9]\\.")
#[1] 3
```

As the OP mentioned `I know the digits I want to count will be 1-9.`, so it should work

Answer (score 2):

Using the regex from @akrun, you can also do this with `base R`:

```
length(grepRaw("\\b[0-9]\\.", this_str, all = TRUE))

[1] 3
```

Or:

```
lengths(regmatches(this_str, gregexpr("\\b[0-9]\\.", this_str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is simply that something follow the period, then this delivers:

```
>  str_count(this_str, "[0-9]\\..")
[1] 3
```

If on hte other hand the requiremnts is that a space faollowt hte digit-period pattern then this:

```
>  str_count(this_str, "[0-9]\\.[ ]")
[1] 3
```

I worried that patterns like digit-digit-period-space- might be missed.